# Uncompressing .tar.gz archive to specific directory

Tags: directory, tar

How does `tar.gz` file gets uncompressed with all contents to arbitrary directory, existing or not using tar using single line command? If it does not exists, then is created (directory). To clarify, let consider example:
I've downloaded `archive-latest.tar.gz` from internet into directory `/home/user/Downloads`. I have microSD card target partition mounted on `/mnt/archive`. Once downloaded, I want to extract downloaded `/home/user/Downloads/archive-latest.tar.gz` directly on `/mnt/archive` using single line command. I've read `man tar` manual, but I cannot find option for specifying target dir.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question means. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It is simple task but unfortunately I've forgotten it. I want to uncompress .tar.gz archive into some arbitrary directory, for instance `/tmp/test`. But I want it to be done regardless of `/tmp/test` directory existence. If target dir does not exists, then it must be automatically created and then the archive is extracted into it.

Comment: You mean the extracted tar directory would be inside `/tmp/test`? And where would the original tar file be placed? I suggest an "imaginary" example session to show the kind of behavior you want.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, I've ugpraded question with simple example, what I want to achieve.

Comment: You made some comment about a directory being created as necessary. What directory would need to be created in your example?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, let's forget about that part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-C` option makes tar change to an **existing** directory before starting to extract:

```
 tar xv -C /mnt/archive -f /home/user/Downloads/archive-latest.tar.gz
```

If you are already located in the directory `/home/user` or `/home/user/Downloads` you can shorten the path after `-f` accordingly.

If there is a chance the target path doesn't exist you can created it with `mkdir`:

```
 mkdir -p /mnt/archive;  tar xv -C /mnt/archive -f /home/user/Downloads/archive-latest.tar.gz
```

With the `-p` option `mkdir` doesn't complain in case the directory already exists.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih The man page for that option is IMO overly simplistic